# Problem with accessing Stack Overflow under a localhost proxy

Tags: bug, status-declined, proxy

For some reasons, I am using a localhost proxy configured as "HTTP CONNECT Tunneling". 
When I open anything under `stackoverflow.com`, I get a runtime error page.

I think this is because my proxy adds an HTTP header:

```
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR == 127.0.0.1
```

How can my problem be fixed?

Comment: Um. Don't use a local proxy?

Comment: I know the concept of a proxy...you send stuff through it so that the receiving end does not see it is you, but instead only sees the proxy. But what does a local proxy do?

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby: that's only *one* possible use of a proxy, the technique can be used for many different gains: filtering unwanted content, anonymization (what you mentioned), "adding value" (usually ads), ensuring that rules are followed, ...

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Oh yeah right, altering content on the fly...completely forgot about that, thanks. :)

Comment: Sounds like a broken fix for the vulnerability that allowed you to access debug/admin features on SO by setting this header.

Comment: No repro. Either a stealth fix or your problem lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't make sense to invest time in (and continuing supporting) this very narrow use case.

Especially since it should be possible to fix on your end, we're not going out of our way to detect proxies or anything.